# URL doesn't like ampersand

Tags: php

Do I have to worry about the error warning (**Notice: Undefined index: page in**...) when the url is `username=guest&amp;page=1` since previously it was `username=guest&page=1`?

It only happens when I test 'log in' and 'log off'.

The URL comes from `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

Any way to just convert `&amp;` back to  `&`?

If not, I'll just find a way to remove

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars()` on that url?

Comment: I think was adding too much security to every input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're using `htmlspecialchars` on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. If you just echoed the request URI, you'd have no problems with the ampersands.

Comment: Sanitizing the url using FILTER_SANITIZE_URL filter would be good, right?

Comment: Sanitizing should be fine. At least you won't get `&amp;`.